# trying to use dyn AsyncReadExt, "the trait cannot be made into an object" error

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

I'm working on a network service that's intended to work with either a TcpStream or stdin/stdout. I get a compile error: `the trait tokio::io::util::async_read_ext::AsyncReadExt cannot be made into an object`. Currently my workaround is to use a wrapper enum:

```
enum ClientReader {
    Stream(OwnedReadHalf),
    Stdin(Stdin),
}

enum ClientWriter {
    Stream(OwnedWriteHalf),
    Stdout(Stdout),
}
```

This requires `match` blocks all over the place, which seems inelegant.

I made a simplified project to repro the issue:

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "demo"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["test"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "0.2", features = ["full"] }
```

src/main.rs

```
use tokio::io::AsyncReadExt;

struct Test {
  test: Box<dyn AsyncReadExt>,
}

fn main () {}
```

This produces a similar error:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `tokio::io::AsyncReadExt` cannot be made into an object
    --> src/main.rs:4:3
     |
4    |   test: Box<dyn AsyncReadExt>,
     |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `tokio::io::AsyncReadExt` cannot be made into an object
     |
    ::: /home/???/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-0.2.22/src/io/util/async_read_ext.rs:162:12
     |
162  |         fn read<'a>(&'a mut self, buf: &'a mut [u8]) -> Read<'a, Self>
     |            ---- the trait cannot be made into an object because method `read` references the `Self` type in its return type
...
280  |         fn read_exact<'a>(&'a mut self, buf: &'a mut [u8]) -> ReadExact<'a, Self>
     |            ---------- the trait cannot be made into an object because method `read_exact` references the `Self` type in its return type
```

I'm not sure how to proceed. I was considering a giant `impl` block for the `enum` wrapper, but that seems like more work than the `match` blocks. In an OO language there'd be a parent class or interface so I investigated the `trait_enum` crate to automate making a wrapper `impl` but had a lot of trouble getting that to work.

At the moment the only cleanup I'm sure will work is to move the workaround into a macro or function.

I'd appreciate any feedback on a better way to do this. :)

EDIT: per suggestion by user4815162342 I made the struct generic over type `AsyncReadExt` and this appears to work for my example. Will try on my larger project later.

```
use tokio::io::AsyncReadExt;

struct Test<T: AsyncReadExt> {
  test: T,
}

async fn myfn<T: AsyncReadExt>(mut t: Test<T>) where T: std::marker::Unpin {
    let mut v = Vec::<u8>::new();
    t.test.read_buf(&mut v).await;
}

fn main () {}
```

Comment: Have you considered making your struct _generic_ over the trait? For example, [`struct Test<T: AsyncReadExt> { test: T, }`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=345c4a31ab2fc9c24d48f1cc436b3867)? And if you need to place different `Test<T>` into the same box, you can make your own trait, which is object-safe, and use `Box<dyn ThatTrait>` to store your structs.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! I had to add a "where T: Unpin" clause to the generic but I got my example to compile

Answer (score 1):

To turn an `AsyncRead` into a trait object, you should use the type `Pin<Box<dyn AsyncRead>>`.

```
use std::pin::Pin;
use tokio::io::AsyncRead;

struct Test {
    test: Pin<Box<dyn AsyncRead>>,
}

impl Test {
    fn new<T: AsyncRead>(io: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            test: Box::pin(io),
        }
    }
}
```

The `AsyncReadExt` trait is an extension trait, and you should always use the `AsyncRead` trait when mentioning the type of an `AsyncRead`.